# how to check multi div scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs on my page with different classes 
how can I check which div is scrolled to the top and therefore do something.

```
<div class="menu-session-0">
  content
</div>
<div class="menu-session-1">
  content
</div>
<div class="menu-session-2">
  content
</div>
```

I already tried this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var hT = $('.session-index_1').offset().top,
    hH = $('.session-index_1').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop() + 175;
    if(hT <= (wS + 250)){
      $('.menu-item').removeClass('menu-item_active');
      $('.item-index-1').addClass('menu-item_active');
      mySwiper.slideTo(1);
      mySwiper.update();
    }
  },1050);
});
```

But it did not work as I expected...

Comment: it worked but when i scroll to the div and then goes to the next div mySwiper get confused

Comment: As I understand. You are trying to make scrollable divs, and you want to do something when you scroll to the top of each div?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want the elements to do/check. Are you checking which element is at the top? or do you have multiple scrollable elements? If so you should check element height and scroll position within that element.

Comment: yes @AlirezaAzimi

Comment: @zergski i know that but there is no other way?

Comment: well .. yes. Because you're otherwise checking the scroll of the page.. which will return true only once, when body is scrolled to top and '.session-index_1' elements offset is less than 125..

Comment: are your elements positioned in a column order or next to each other in a row?

Comment: @zergski you can check this link to see the div's : http://labb.ir/grano/landing - each background image is a div

Comment: Wait.. your  `$('.item-index-1').addClass('menu-item_active');` is looking for element with the class of 'item-index-1' while your elements classes are defined as 'session-index_1' or am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: the '.item-index-1' is my slider and $('.item-index-1').addClass('menu-item_active'); is for activation

Comment: ah okey gotit.. give me a sec

Comment: @zergski at my question on script part; my script can detect each div but activing special slide with mySwiper.slideTo(1); get confused and moving to forward and backward and with a delay active the slide

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I get it now, I think.. :P

This should (in theory) work just fine if you copy and paste instead of your code.

If you really want to use JQuery just replace the element reference getters and class writers

```
const menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
const menuSessions = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-session');

var nextSession, activeSession;

// do this to get menu-session offsets.. rerun function on viewport resize
function getSessionOffset() {
    for( let session of menuSessions ) {
        // store position and dataset.index directy on the element reference
        session.y = session.offsetTop;  
        session.indx = session.dataset.index;
    }
    // define active elements which position we listen for
    // these are correct if the window scroll offset is 0 (or at the top)
    activeSession = menuSessions[0];
    nextSession = menuSessions[1];
    onScroll(window.pageYOffset);       // so we check and set the correct active elements
}
getSessionOffset();

// page scroll listener
window.addEventListener( 'scroll' , ScrollHandler );

var lastScrollPos = 0;      // last recorded window scroll offset
var scrollTick = false;     // the tick is used to throttle code execution

function ScrollHandler (ev) {
    lastScrollPos = ev.target.scrollTop;

    if (!scrollTick) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {        // <- read up on this if you are not familiar. Very usefull
            onScroll(lastScrollPos);
            scrollTick = false;
        });
        scrollTick = true;
    }
}

function onScroll(scrollY) {
    if (scrollY > nextSession.y) {  // if lower offset is less than scrollPos
        removeActiveClass(activeSession.indx);      // we remove the active class from menu item

        activeSession = menuSessions[nextSession.indx];     // define new elements to listen for
        nextSession = menuSessions[nextSession.indx + 1];

        addActiveClass(activeSession.indx);     // and add an active class to the new menu item

    } else if (scrollY < activeSession.y) {     // do the same here only in reverse
        removeActiveClass(activeSession.indx);

        nextSession = menuSessions[activeSession.indx];
        activeSession = menuSessions[nextSession.indx - 1];

        addActiveClass(activeSession.indx);
    }
}

function removeActiveClass(indx) {
    menuItems[indx].classList.remove('menu-item_active');
}
function addActiveClass(indx) {
    menuItems[indx].classList.add('menu-item_active');
}
```

We listen only for the current and next values.
This may look like a lot but can be shortened to a third of the size.

Hope this helps :)